# How can I reposition page elements of a PDF and write to a new PDF?

Tags: perl, pdf, label

I would like to take a rectangular [packaging label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBzpl.jpg) in PDF format, consisting of mostly formatted text, a few images and borders, and take the four main elements of this PDF (marked each in red in the image) and reposition them into a new PDF so that it can be printed on my 62mm label printer.
There are several free web services available who can do this for more common packaging labels, but not the ones that I need, so I would like to code this myself (preferrably in Perl).
Any pointers on how to approach this task would be very helpful - thanks!

[image]

Comment: Convert PDF to sufficiently hi-res image. Crop out the parts. Optionally scale/rotate. Combine into new image. Convert back to PDF. You could probably do it with just a simple shell script calling graphicsmagick.

Comment: If you rebuild the label, the scanners won't be able to read it any more. If all you have is a 62mm printer, talk to your Deutsche Post account manager to see if they have a service that can produce different size labels. I know DPD can do that, I'm sure DHL can do it too.

Comment: @simbabque: No, that is not true. I'm using online services such as www.paketikett.de/ for quite a while now on my QL-800 62mm printer, and there never has been a problem. The barcodes in the original PDFs are just images of 1 pixel height which are then scaled vertically, so that should not be a problem. In fact, pdftohtml extracts the images and text in separate files without a problem, the question is only how to also extract the original order and get them back in a different order afterwards. Also, the font is not detected properly through this way (always Times New Roman instead of Helv)

Comment: @jhnc: Thanks, that could work, but I'm not aware of a command line tool that generates an image out of a (text-based with some graphics) PDF. Do you happen to know one?

Comment: As I said - [graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/): `tmp=WBzpl.jpg; gm convert -scale 854x603 in.pdf $tmp; gm convert $tmp -crop 570x148+284+0 -rotate 90 $tmp -crop 570x220+284+148 -rotate 90 $tmp -crop 570x603+284+368 -rotate 90 $tmp -crop 284x603+0+0 -append out.pdf; rm $tmp`

Comment: Fair enough. I've been doing this on a larger commercial scale for a big e-com company years ago, and we never actually worked with DHL. They didn't support the kind of things we shipped very well. I would usually just call the DPD guy for our location and talk to them directly. There was a dedicated computer running the DPD software to generate labels in our warehouses, and that would be used via some API, with the machine then printing and labelling parcels going through a conveyor belt automatically. When I dealt with UPS US they had a SOAP API that returned full label images as well.

Comment: penultimate 603 should have been 235. `tmp=WBzpl.jpg; w=854; h=603; x=284; y1=148; y2=368; gm convert -scale ${w}x${h} in.pdf $tmp; gm convert $tmp -crop $((w-x))x${y1}+${x}+0 -rotate 90 $tmp -crop $((w-x))x$((y2-y1))+${x}+${y1} -rotate 90 $tmp -crop $((w-x))x$((h-y2))+${x}+${y2} -rotate 90 $tmp -crop ${x}x${h}+0+0 -append out.pdf`

Comment: @jhnc: Wow, that's awesome, thanks! Would you add this as a regular answer so I can mark it as a solution? The only problem is indeed that the compression produces quite some artefacts which may result in the scanner at the post office not being able to read the bar code correctly (even with the regular ones I sometimes have this problem because the thermo printer quality is not comparable to a laser or so). Is there a configuration option for that available? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to:

- convert PDF to sufficiently hi-res image
- crop out the individual pieces
- re-scale/rotate
- combine into new image
- optionally convert back to PDF

For example, for the image and cropping from the sample image provided in the question, a shell script using [graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) might be:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# graphicsmagick uses the file extension to decide file type

in=in.pdf     # original (pdf expected)
tmp=tmp.png   # temporary image (png is lossless)
out=out.pdf   # output file (or use png for image)

# convert original pdf to bitmap image
#   density is dpi - larger gives higher resolution
gm convert -density 300 $in $tmp

# find size of resulting image, for use below
file $tmp

# width/height of bounding box temporary image will fit into
#   probably needs to be much bigger than this
#   this script just uses the resolution of the question's image
w=854
h=603

# important x/y distances in the image
# change to match width/height given above
x=284
y1=148
y2=368

# crop out the individual pieces, rotate so long side is vertical,
#   then combine (append) into a single output file
# format is: [width] "x" [height] "+" [x offset] "+" [y offset]
gm convert \
    $tmp -crop $((w-x))x${y1}+${x}+0          -rotate 90 \
    $tmp -crop $((w-x))x$((y2-y1))+${x}+${y1} -rotate 90 \
    $tmp -crop $((w-x))x$((h-y2))+${x}+${y2}  -rotate 90 \
    $tmp -crop ${x}x${h}+0+0 \
    -append $out

# clean up
rm $tmp
```

Note that `-append` seems to combine images in an unexpected order:

```sh
gm convert $in1 $in2 $in3 $in4 -append $out

# $out contains a vertical stack of $in4, $in1, $in2, $in3
# (ie. $in4 appears at the top rather than at the bottom)
```

Comment: As the input file is a PDF file and not an image that I used as a workaround in the original question, is there a way to define the output size of the conversion from PDF to image so that the output image becomes a higher resolution image than the image in the original question? I've tried adjusting w and h etc. to ten times their values, but in the end the pixels just get larger. What I would need is that gm "looks" at the PDF as if the PDF is scaled/magnified to like 10 times its standard aspect ratio and then converted to image. Is that possible?

Comment: I've changed the answer to use `-density` instead of `-scale`

Comment: Again, thanks a lot, it works like charm now and the barcodes are easily readable. I've changed the code a bit by using "gm identify" to obtain the image size variables w and h and also so that the individual sections become individual pages in the PDF (I've done this by joining the PNGs not via gm but through img2pdf) so that my printer does automatic cutting in-between. This really saves a lot of paper for me in the future because the original PDF would center the label in the middle of an A4 page where the rest would go to waste. Thanks a lot again, I've learned a lot today :)...

Comment: Cool. FWIW, to get multi-page pdf, you could just leave off `-append`.

Comment: I tried that as well, but one of the cropped images (which turned out fine in "append"-mode) resulted in one very long and very narrow page with no content. No idea why. With img2pdf it turned out fine, so I stuck with that.